# MVC: Using controller that is defined in a referenced project

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have an MVC project A that references another project B. Is it possible to make an ajax call to an action method in a controller that is defined in project B?

```
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "/ThatController/CountyJSON/?Country=" + $('#JobCountry').val()...
```

What should I put in place of "ThatController"?

Thanks.

Comment: the route to the controller in the other project....

Comment: @DanField The project A refers to a B.dll. How should the path look? url: "/B/Controllers/ThanController/CountyJSON/... doesn't work.

Comment: You could probably define some kind of custom route, but do you have a working url for the other project?

Comment: @DanField What is working url in this case? The code is there, but it is not a part of the project.
The dll is referenced like: C:\Projects\SomeFolder\Libraries\MPATS.dll

Comment: Right, you have to deploy that project as well.

Comment: @DanField Maybe you could formulate your suggestion in more detail as an answer, so that I could mark it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure both projects are deployed.  In other words, Project B needs to be deployed in much the same way you deploy Project A.

Then, you can simply call the controller route for Project B, using the URL to it, just as if you were calling a controller route in Project A.  Your AJAX call doesn't need anything else special - unless Project B is deployed on a different domain, in which case you need to look into CORS.